# mysql millions of rows data import from one table to another table

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a table, it has two millions rows data. For each row, it has a `body` column, it store a JSON format data. For example:

**table_a:**

```
id user_id  body
1  1        {'tel': '13678031283', 'email': 'test@gmail.com', 'name': 'test'....}
2  2        {'tel' : '1567827126', 'age': '16'....}
......
```

I have another table, named table_b:

**table_b:**

```
id     user_id    tel        email         name
1      1          13678019   test@qq.com   test1
2      2          15627378   test1@qq.com  test2  
.....
```

table_a has 2 million rows data, I want to import all table_a data to table_b, each row of table_a should be process.

I want to deal with it like this:

```
for row in table_a_rows:
    result = process(row)
    insert result to table_b
.....
```

But i think it is not a good idea. it there a better way to make it?

Comment: There is an extension for mysql / mariadb that allows to treat such annoying json structures as "virtual columns". That way you can use a plain sql update statement for your task without the need to implement a stored procedure.

Comment: I don't want to each keys of body as single column, I just want to get I needed info.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you try to say in your last comment. You need access to the content of the JSON structure as if the values were stored in separate columns. This is what the extension allows. This way you can split the contents of those JSON strings to separate values which you then again can use in an update statement. That is what you ask, unless I totally miss understood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the data you need from table_a directly with `JSON_EXTRACT`. For example, getting the email would be something like this:

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(body, '$.email') from table_a;
```

So you could replace directly into table_b all the data you have in table_a:

```
mysql> REPLACE INTO table_b SELECT user_id, 
JSON_EXTRACT(body, '$.tel'),
JSON_EXTRACT(body,'$.email'), 
JSON_EXTRACT(body,'$.name') from table_a
```

Comment: got the error: `FUNCTION JSON_EXTRACT does not exist`

Comment: ops, sorry, you have to install a json library for mysql. Visit labs.mysql.com and install the JSON UDFs (user defined functions). Check the Readme for that.